# Backup Optimization

Tags: oracle, backup

The production database is configured to backup with parallelism 16. I noticed that first 16 channels is allocated and each channel backups 61 datafiles, after that, next 16 channels backup 20 datafile (PS:each channel backups 20 dbf), next 16 channels backup 5 datafile, in the last cycle each channel backups 1 datafile. It causes to increase backup time. I want to manage a static number of datafile count for each backup channel cycle.

Comment: As long as the total size of data being backed up by each channel for a run is roughly even, there shouldn’t be a problem. How long is this taking? How much data is there to backup? Do you have the bandwidth to support 16 channels? What is the storage?

Comment: Database is RAC with 2 database server on Exadata. Each database server is connected over infiniband to ZFS storage server. Each instance is allocated 8 channels .Backup of 30TB data takes 8.30 hours. Infiniband speed should be 40Gb , it should take 3-4 hours. Speed changes during backup ,it is not in peak and another problem is datafile count, which in each cycle it decreases datafile count for each channel and it also affect backup time.

Comment: Just for fun, have you tried running with parallelism 8? 32?  How many CPUs total across your RAC?

Comment: 96 CPU per node, Oracle best practice is that 8 channel for each instance. I tried to increase parallelism from 1 to 8 channel for each instance, this reduce backup time, but after 8 channel it doesn't give any advantage. I should adjust other parameters because increasing parallelism affected infiniband speed, but it still doesn't work with full performance.